# SharePoint 2016 : Is there any React Taxanomy Picker Control that can be used in a SharePoint FrameWork WebPart (React)

Tags: managed-metadata, taxonomy, sharepoint-framework

I have to implement a SharePoint Form with Taxomomy Fields in a SharePoint FrameWork WebPart (React).
Is there any React Taxanomy Picker Control I can use ?

Regards,

Arioule

Answer (score 1):

GDPR ActivityHub has one implemented. You can find it here https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-gdpr-activity-hub/blob/master/GDPRStarterKit/src/components/SPTaxonomyPicker.tsx